# shared driver's permissions on a dual boot machine

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, window

I am a **.net** **Developer who's currently moving to Linux world**, I managed to install both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on the same machine. I can access my windows partitions from Ubuntu which is great, but I have my own workspace for PHP development that I want to share between the two Operating Systems. I tried to create a virtual host on Apache2 for a folder resides on NTFS partition (which is my `D:\ partition` on windows) but when I open the browser and navigate to the virtual host address I get error number `403 permission` denied from Apache.

It's obvious it's permission related issue. however I've set the ownership and the permissions from Ubuntu using the chown and chmod commands but still, I get the same error, which led me to believe its related to the fact that the folder belongs to windows and formatted in NTFS. I wonder if there is a way I can get this issue resolved. the reason I need to have my workspace shared between Windows and Ubuntu is that I use both OS's for development because I need more time learning Linux until I can move to It preeminently.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error you will encounter if you havent done the below :

reboot to you windows OS , and there do the following

1) Go to "power options" , which will come up when you right click on the battery icon

2) On your left , open either of these : -> choose what power button does -> choose what closing the lid does

3) you will see a link on top which says : -> (adminSymbol)"change settings that are currently unavailable"

4) remove all the ticks of , fast startup , sleeo , hibernate and lock ,

5) save the changes and reboot the system ,

6) and , check if you can access the windows directories from your ubuntu machine ! , i am sure you will be able to :) .

I hope this helped , this should solve your problem ,